# Opencv Python, how to choose appropiated videocodec + file extension on diferent OS

Tags: python, opencv

im trying to create my own survillance camera for my farm using a Rpi3, i manage to set the Flask server, and im try to set an auto selection for the videocodec and file extension, but i found really hard to actually found a working conbination that actualy works, im running the program on MacosX High Sierra (for testing purpose) and the RPi 3 but im thinking on running that either on a BBB or RPi Zero W, thats why im setting the auto option before i save, but i have no real way to check if that works for my system, the way i do it is basically create the **cv2.VideoWriter()** and check with **is.Opened()**

Theres any way to actually check with the system what videocodec and file extension actually works with out checking manually? the codecs are XVID, mp4v, or h.264. i found the video codecs from here
https://web.archive.org/web/20120722124832/http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/QuickTimeCodecs

outputFrame is where i set the capture image from the camera, and can be used for motion detection

```
def save():
    global outputFrame, lock
    codec = False
    
    archivo = 'camera_' + datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%I-%M_%p") 
    camera = cap.isOpened()
    archivo_mp4 = archivo + '.mp4'
    archivo_xvid = archivo + '.xvid'
    archivo_avi = archivo + '.avi'
    
    try:
        ###############    #mp4v saving
        videocodec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m','p','4','v')     # mp4v codec  
        print('checking mp4v')
        print(archivo_mp4)
        salida = cv2.VideoWriter(archivo_mp4, videocodec, 32.0,(1920,1080) )  #(int(cap.get(3)), int((cap.get(4)))))
        codec = salida.isOpened()
      #Check if the camera is open and the codec is working
        if ((camera == True) & (codec == True)):
            print('Camera and video codec properly loaded, mp4v + mp4')
            log('Camera and video codec properly loaded, mp4v + mp4')        
        else:
            salida.release()
            del codec
            salida = cv2.VideoWriter(archivo_avi, videocodec, 32.0,(1920,1080) )  #(int(cap.get(3)), int((cap.get(4)))))
            codec = salida.isOpened()
            if ((camera ==True) & (codec == True)):
                print('Camera and video codec properly loaded, mp4v + avi')
                log('Camera and video codec properly loaded, mp4v + avi')
            else:   
                salida.release()
                del codec
                del videocodec
     #############           #XVID saving
                videocodec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')    #XVID 
                print('checking XVID')
                print(archivo_avi)
                salida = cv2.VideoWriter(archivo_avi, videocodec, 32.0,(1920,1080) )  #(int(cap.get(3)), int((cap.get(4)))))
                codec = salida.isOpened()
                if ((camera == True) & (codec == True)):
                    print('Camera and video codec properly loaded, XVID + avi')
                    log('Camera and video codec properly loaded, XVID + avi')
                else:
                    salida.release()
                    del codec
                    print(archivo_xvid)
                    salida = cv2.VideoWriter(archivo_xvid, videocodec, 32.0, (1920,1080) )                    
                    codec = salida.isOpened()
                    if ((camera == True) & (codec == True)):
                        print('Camera and video codec properly loaded, XVID + xvid')
                        log('Camera and video codec properly loaded, XVID + xvid')
                    else:
                        salida.release()
                        del codec
                        del videocodec                  
       #############          #H.264 saving
                        videocodec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('a','v','c','1')    # H.264 codec works but need to erase or create a new file first                
                        print('checking h264')
                        print(archivo_mp4)
                        salida = cv2.VideoWriter(archivo_mp4, videocodec, 32.0,(1920,1080) )  #(int(cap.get(3)), int((cap.get(4)))))
                        codec = salida.isOpened()
                        if ((camera == True) & (codec == True)):
                            print('Camera and video codec properly loaded, h.264 + mp4')
                            log('Camera and video codec properly loaded, h.264 + mp4')
                        else:
                            salida.release()
                            del codec
                            print(archivo_avi)
                            salida = cv2.VideoWriter(archivo_avi, videocodec, 32.0,(1920,1080) )
                            codec = salida.isOpenend()
                            if ((camera == True) & (codec == True)):
                                print('Camera and video codec properly loaded, XVID + xvid')
                                log('Camera and video codec properly loaded, XVID + xvid')       
        
        #Check if the camera is open and the codec is working                         
        if ((camera == True) & (codec == False)):
            print('camera working but unable to load video codec for saving video')
            log('camera working but unable to load video codec for saving video')
        if ((camera == False) & (codec == False)):
            print('Unable to load camera and video codec')
            log('Unable to load camera and video codec')
        if ((camera == False) & (codec == True)):
            print('Camera unable to load, but video codec loaded properly')
            log('Camera unable to load, but video codec loaded properly')
        
        while ((cap.isOpened()) & (codec == True)):  # only saves the files if the camera and codec are loaded correctly
            
            ret, frame = cap.read()  # read the actual frame using Opencv
            outputFrame = frame.copy()
            
            with lock:
                if outputFrame is None:
                    continue
                width = outputFrame.shape[1]       # retrieve the width of the frame
                flipFrame = cv2.flip(outputFrame, 1)   #makes sure the frame is fliped
                fecha = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
                # set the date on the current frame
                cv2.putText(flipFrame, fecha,(14, flipFrame.shape[0]-15), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.65, (0,0,255), 1 )  
            
                if width != 1920:       # resizes and write the frame to the video file
                    rezisedFrame = cv2.resize(flipFrame, (1920,1080), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
                    salida.write(rezisedFrame)
                else:
                    salida.write(flipFrame)
                #else:
                #    log('frame size dont match, cannot create video file: ' + str(width))
                    
        salida.release()
        log('video file created succesfully')       
    except:
        log("not working")
```

Comment: maybe use `for`-loop to test different combinations of codecs and file extensions. (because some codecs don't work with some file extensions)

Comment: few years ago I tested different codecs with different file extensions and I keep information in code [main-test-extensions.py](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/save-file/main-test-extensions.py) but all may depends what codecs you have installed in system.

Comment: @furas, i did check your code and it help me, but i had to check manually wich combination works best, i ended with mp4v or XVID + avi files on the Rpi, but now the speed of the video is like 2x normal playback not sure whats happening, meabe the video codec needs to set the speed?, videocodecs are harder than expected

Comment: `VideoWriter(..., 32, ...)` doesn't mean that it will create video with speed 32 frames per second but it is only information for video players how fast to display it. But if you will add only 16 frames in every seconds then video players will display it 2x speed. You have to change this value to real speed which you add frames to file.

Comment: You may need to run code in two threads: One thread has to create new frame as fast as it can. Other thread has to add to file frame every `31.25 ms` (1000ms/32fps = 31.25ms) - and it doesn't matter if there is new frame or still old frame. This way it will create video which will have real 32 frames for every second.

Comment: ill be honest i cant remember why i set that to 32, i did change it to 24 fps on the final commit, it only happends when i use mp4v + avi, but if i use h264 like this avc1 + mp4 the video is played properly, i would try your advice on adding a new frame every X ms,  the final code is here **[Code](https://github.com/lightshadown/Opencv-Security-Camera/blob/master/Flask_camera.py)**

Comment: you could use `time.time()` to check time before getting frame and after processing frame to see how long it takes. Maybe `mp4v + avi` needs longer time - so it may process less frames per second and later it gives wrong speed in video. You could also use this value to calculate average frames per seconds and use it to write video with correct value.